# Mono: flatMap to load another item then return original item

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I am just starting with Spring Webflux and I was wondering if the following call is a good way to load additional items in a reactive stream and if there is maybe another operator that can simplify this call:

```
Mono<Foo> fooMono = fooService.loadFoo();
fooMono.flatMap(foo -> barService.loadBarForFoo(foo).flatMap(bar -> Mono.just(foo)))
```

For example: `fooMono` might be something loaded via a `WebClient` and `barService.loadBarFromFoo`  would know how to load a `Bar` given a `Foo` and then insert `bar` into `foo`. In the end I want to get `foo` back to perform some more actions, like loading another resource into `foo`.

Is it good practice to create a new Mono from `foo` in the end or is there maybe even another operator that can be used to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you could use `thenReturn` supposing you do not need to use the result of `loadBarForFoo` method.

```
fooMono.flatMap(foo -> barService.loadBarForFoo(foo).thenReturn(foo));
```